# Gitlabs CI Runner Does Not Resolve Hostnames

Tags: dns, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I created a specific runner following this guide: [Install using official GitLab repositories(Linux)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-repository.md). I was able to successfully register the runner in our company GitLab.

I also provided a **.gitlab-ci.yml** for our gradle project. Basically it's as simple as this:

```
image: java:8-jdk

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew check
```

Once GitLab saw this file it started to run a build but failed with:

```
$ ./gradlew assemble
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
```

I worked around this problem by updating the **extra_hosts** in my local **/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml**:

```
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.1"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    extra_hosts = ["git.my.company.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","services.gradle.org:207.223.250.8","downloads.gradle.org:54.240.162.161","repo1.maven.org:151.101.36.209"]
  [runners.cache]
```

As you can see I had to to do this for every hostname that is used during the build. Now I can run a build with GitLab CI but I have to provide this cumbersome setting. I'd rather would like to see the runner pulling the IP addresses from DNS.

Has anybody experienced the same problem? Is there any known solution?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I can add DNS settings to the runner config like that:

```
[runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.1"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    dns = ["<my company's DNS IP>"]
```

I still wonder why I need those settings. I mean the system where the runner is running also knows how to resolve host names w/o further configuration.

Comment: Could you confirm it works from outside of gitlab-ci runner but from the same system user?

Comment: Yes. I did a **ping** to the unresolved host names from the system user to make the settings above.